# Ant SVN partial build

Tags: java, svn, build, ant

I am currently working in a java application(web) where 'ANT'is used as a build tool and SVN as version control tool. This application contains 100's of java files and every time a small change occurs to any of the java file, the build process is taking all files into consideration for building the WAR file. Is there any possibility that, if one file is changed, only that particular file should get compiled and packed into the existing WAR file ?

So here is my requirement in short.

1. Identify modified files
2. Compile modified files and generate .class files
3. Open the existing WAR file, replace modified class files into it and closethe WAR file.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: I would advise against this.  Better to clean out the old WAR file and recreate it from scratch each time.  Packaging a WAR is more than recompiling classes.  You should be running unit tests, etc.

Comment: You should also consider to use a Java IDE like IntellJ, Eclipse or Netbeans. These allow shorter development cycles without the need to build the full WAR file and partial compilation. Then you only have to build the WAR via Ant to deploy a new version.

Comment: Hi Duffymo & Vanje, Thank you for your comments. My main intention behind this question is for faster development purposes. Every time i am making a change, build process is almost taking 6 to 9 minutes of time. Just to avoid this i am looking for a simple build solution.